# Probablity question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A box of clothes contains 15 shirts and 10 pants. Three items are drawn from the box without replacement. What is the probability that all three are all shirts or all pants?

The correct answer is $0.25$ and thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? We are not answering machines and would be far more willing to help if you showed some attempt at solving the problem. I will confirm that $1/4$ is the right answer though; so whoever told you this is correct. I will hint that $P(\text{three pants or three shirts}) = P(\text{three pants}) + P(\text{three shirts})$.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry. That was my first post here and I did try a lot to solve it, I just never thought of putting it all up here. I'll make sure to include that the next time :) I kept trying to solve it with the probablity for shirts with 3/15 and 3/10 for the pants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability, as Chris K pointed out, is equal to the sum of the probability of drawing three pants and the probability of drawing three pants.

*Lets start with the probability of drawing three pants:*

On the first draw, you would have to draw pants. $\frac{10}{25}$ of the objects are pants, and so the chance is $\frac{10}{25}$.

On the second draw, you would also have to draw pants. $\frac{9}{24}$ of the objects are pants (as pants are not replaced, and so there is no longer on pair of pants in the box), and so the chance is $\frac{9}{24}$.

On the third draw, again, you would have to draw pants. $\frac{8}{23}$ of the objects are pants.

The probability of all three of these instances occurring is equal to the product of the sums. Thus, the chance of drawing three pants is $\frac{10}{25} \times \frac{9}{24} \times \frac{8}{23} = \frac{720}{13800}=\frac{6}{115}$.

You can do the same for the shirts, and find that the probability is $\frac{91}{460}$.

Summing these probabilities:

$\frac{6}{115}+\frac{91}{460} =\frac{1}{4}$

Thus, the chance is $\frac{1}{4}=0.25$.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, helped a lot